# Is it safe not to destroy an object of a class type that is a member of a union?

Tags: c++, class, destructor, unions

I have this example:

```
struct A{
    A(){std::cout << "A's def-ctor\n";}
    ~A(){std::cout << "A's dtor\n";}
    A(A const&){std::cout << "A's copy-ctor\n";}
    A& operator = (A const&){std::cout << "A's copy-assign op\n"; return *this; }
};

struct Foo{
    Foo() : curMem_(INT), i_(0){}
    ~Foo(){
        if(curMem_ == CLS_A) // If I comment out this line then what happens?
            a_.~A();
    }
    enum {INT, CHAR, CLS_A, BOOL} curMem_;
    union{
        int i_;
        char c_;
        A a_;
        bool b_;
    };
};

Foo f;
f.curMem_ = Foo::CLS_A;
f.a_ = A();

f.curMem_ = Foo::BOOL;
f.b_ = true;
```

- We know that a class default destructor doesn't know which member of a class's member of a union type is active that is why we do need to define out version of destructor. So union's member data of class type are not automatically destroyed. So What will happen if I don't explicitly call the destructor of those class type member of the union?
- If I comment the line in `Foo` destructor or remove the destructor itself what will happen? Is it undefined behavior?
- My class `A` doesn't manage a resource via a raw pointer then why I bother to explicitly call its destructor when an of object of it is a member of a `union`? Thank you!

P.S: I have this from C++ primer 5th edition Chapter 19.6 unions:

> Our destructor checks whether the object being destroyed holds a string. If so, the destructor explicitly calls the string destructor (§ 19.1.2, p. 824) to free the memory used by that string. The destructor has no work to do if the union holds a member of any of the built-in types.

"The destructor has no work to do if the union holds a member of any of the built-in types." I think he could add: "or of a class type which depends on the trivial destructor". What do you think?

Comment: For what it's worth, you should also consider calling the destructor of `A` while `a_` is still the active member right before you assign to `b_`

Comment: @alterigel: This is just an example to understand what will happen in case I don't call the dtor explicitly. I know in a real program I should overload the copy-assignment operator and inside which I should check like in the dtor before assignment.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Think about it the other way: "Hey, I've written my very nice RAII class and now someone puts it in a `union`, should I be worried?"

Comment: If A's destructor doesn't get called, then the effect is that A's destructor doesn't get called.  How problematic that is will depend entirely on what A's destructor would have done -- e.g. if A is a POD class, then nothing of value is lost, because A's destructor was a no-op anyway.  OTOH e.g. if A was holding some resource that A's destructor was expected to free, then you've just leaked that resource forever.  (Note the leak would still occur even if A was holding the resource via a smart-pointer, as the smart-pointer's destructor wouldn't get called)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I think this would be the best answer. So would you add it as answer please?

Comment: I realize this is a bit of a language-lawyer question, but is there any practical reason that you aren't using `std::variant`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact wording of the standard given in `[basic.life]p6` is:

> For an object of a class type, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, **if there is no explicit call to the destructor** or if a delete-expression ([expr.delete]) is not used to release the storage, the destructor is not implicitly called and **any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior**.

(emphasis mine)

"depends on the side effects" seems pretty vague, and there are plenty of questions on stack overflow discussing this wording. Your `A` class's destructor seems to have the side effect of calling an I/O function, so it seems like you run into undefined behaviour.

Even if it wasn't UB, if it was a `std::vector`, `std::string` or `std::fstream`, you would leak resources like memory or file handles. It depends entirely on what the destructor of the class (and any members of that class) do.

---

Since "My class `A` doesn't manage a resource via a raw pointer", it should really have a trivial destructor. In which case, this point is moot and it is fine to not call the destructor.

Comment: _Your A class's destructor seems to have the side effect of calling an I/O function, so it seems like you run into undefined behaviour._ But, the program doesn't _depend_ on this side effect, so it's not UB.